# Groovy loading jar files

Tags: groovy, jar

I loop through a directory to load my jar files

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("C:\\Whatever\\")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { 
    if(it.name.endsWith('.jar')) {
        println it
        this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File(it).toURI().toURL())
    }
}
```

And I get following error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.io.File)

    at ConsoleScript21$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript21:9)

    at ConsoleScript21.run(ConsoleScript21:6)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I load my jar files like this?

Comment: The error most likely complains about your use of `new File(it)` while `it` already is a `File`

Comment: Unless the closure is a one-liner, I always prefer to type out the argument type (if applicable) and name instead of using "it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File(it).toURI().toURL())
```

Should become

```
this.getClass().classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(it.toURI().toURL())
```

`dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES)` iterates over a collection of File objects under the filesystem subtree starting at `"C:\\Whatever\\"`